# Which word is closer to (I'm asking for finding a word for someone "who doesn't know but acting like know"?)

Tags: word-choice, word-request

***Hello everyone.***

At first, thanks for helping me

I'm looking for a word that describe someone:

> With `few or less` information `"about something or an issue in a conversation"`, comes from normal people `"without any credible sources"`, and act like they know but actually don't want to accept that they know nothing about that issue.

An example:

**A)** Do you know **Michael Jordan**? I love him. He is one of the best player I've seen.

**B)** Yes, I love him too. He was a great basketball player. (This person doesn't have enough information about **Michael Jordan** and just knows that he's a basketball player but didn't want to say he didn't know about him and if **A** ask **B** about the teams he was playing in, **B** can't answer that.)

---

**Edit:**
I searched on the internet about my question and got some help from my friends, they suggested these words:

**Know_It_All**

**Abragger/Bragger**

**Normie**

Could you tell me which one is better or closer for this situation or if none of them good enough, what's the word?

Thanks "Sam" and "Friendly Racoon" for your answers. If I get no other answer, I'll accept yours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the idiom : ***fake it***

It implies (As per merriam-webster):-
***to pretend to be something that one is not or to have some knowledge or ability that one does not really have***

Examples:—

*He didn't know the words to the song, so he had to fake it.*

*He acts like he's my friend, but I can tell that he's just faking it.*

Comment: If you are in informal contexts where swearing is appropriate, this is also called "bullshitting" or "speaking out of his bum/ass/arse." Which means lying by speaking confidently about something you don't know. Fake it is definitely the more professional/formal way of saying this